# How to generate .NET classes with comments from WSDL and XSD

Tags: wcf, xsd, annotations, wsdl, comments

There are some XSDs and WSDLs. I want to generate C# code from them. I used svcutil.exe, but it does not generate XML-comments from XSDs annotations:

```
<annotation>
    <documentation>VERY USEFULL DOCUMENTATION</documentation>
</annotation>
```

I want this inside generated file:

```
public class SomeData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// VERY USEFULL DOCUMENTATION
    /// </summary>
    public string SomeField
    {...}
}
```

Another question: how to force svcutil.exe to generate one file per class? (I know that I can use refactor from Resharper to move classes to separate files, but I don't like this solution)

So how to generate multiple files (one file per class) with XML-comments from XSDs and WSDLs

Comment: Your question contains the answer. The tool doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Why do you want them in separate files? These types are generated by the tool, and you're not meant to be changing them. It doesn't matter if they're in one file or a dozen - you shouldn't care what's inside of which file.

Comment: John, I want to do this because of our code policy :)

Comment: Such policies should not apply to generated code. Do your policies apply to Windows Forms .Designer.cs files, for instance? If a tool generates the files, and if they're not read by humans, then most policies should not apply to them. Do your naming convention policies apply? If a field is named "javaStyleName", will you require that it be renamed to "JavaStyleName"?

Comment: This code will be adopted for our needs. At first step it generated from definition of some standard. We use this standard as a starting point to build own infrastructure. So while this code is generated, then it will be used as normal human edited code.

Answer (score 6):

You might be able to use the WCFExtras+ http://wcfextrasplus.codeplex.com/.

1. Make WCFExtras.dll visible to svcutil.exe (such as by putting them in the same directory)
2. add this section to the app.config of the client app, or place in a new config file and invoke svcutil with the /svcutilConfig switch

   ```
    <configuration>
     <system.serviceModel>
       <client>
         <metadata>
           <wsdlImporters>
             <extension type="WCFExtras.Wsdl.Documentation.XmlCommentsImporter, WCFExtras" />
           </wsdlImporters>
         </metadata>
       </client>
     </system.serviceModel>
   </configuration>
   ```

example command line, where configfile.xml is the config file above:
SvcUtil.exe [service url] /svcutilConfig:[path to configfile.xml]

Comment: For future readers: WCFExtras namespace has changed to WFCExtrasPlus and same goes for its assembly name. If you're using fully qualified name, make sure you use the right version & public key token that you can find from comments in library's documentation page (or from assembly itself). The main documentation hasn't been updated in ages and refers to now obsolete version number as public key token

Comment: Not working for me. Svcutil throws `Error: An error occurred in the tool. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Answer (score 1):

I just learned about xsd2Code visual studio add-in.  It does exactly what you want with the Xsd annotation/documentation text moved into a c# xml documentation summary tag.

There is a community version on [CodePlex](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/). The [paid version](http://www.xsd2code.com) has some other nice advanced features so I decided to pay the $45 for a one year license. Note: I'm not part of the company, just a satisfied customer.

Scott Crowder

Comment: xsd2Code is good. I have paid version as well. It has two main drawbacks: it supports only schema (no wsdl/contract); some nullable xml attributes (i.e. decimal) are not handled properly by code generation, so you have to code it manually.

Answer (score -1):

The essential part of the answer is that there is (currently) no way to make the standard tools such as wsdl.exe or svcutil.exe (coming with Windows SDK). You need a separate tool to pre-process the generated proxy files.

Besides the tools from the other answers, if your service definition has `annotation`/`documentation` elements,  [FancyWsdl](https://github.com/Kaupisch-IT/FancyWsdl) can create appropriate summary tags in your C# code, too:

> FancyWsdl post-processes C# proxy code for WSDL service definitions generated by tools such as `wsdl.exe`, `svcutil.exe`, or *Visual Studio > Add Service Reference* and introduces the following enhancements:
>
> - Make it possible to rename types and members
> - Apply C# naming conventions (PascalCase)
> - **Insert documentation (summary tags)**
> - Clean up code

1. Generate C# proxy classes from WSDL file, e.g.

   - `wsdl.exe https://example.com/ExampleService/?wsdl`
   - `svcutil.exe https://example.com/ExampleService/?wsdl`
   - Visual Studio > Add Service Reference
2. **Run *FancyWsdl* on generated code** and **pass service definition(s)**,
   e.g. `fancywsdl.exe ExampleService.cs https://example.com/ExampleService/?wsdl https://example.com/ExampleData.xsd`