# Create a proxy class with summary from a wsdl using svcutil

Tags: c#, svcutil.exe

Is there anyway to generate a proxy class (c# code) from a wsdl using svcutil, that include suumary (this is the documentation for class, methods, ...).

Comment: Maybe there are useful answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617592/how-to-generate-net-classes-with-comments-from-wsdl-and-xsd

Comment: duplicate of [how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950150/how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call)

Comment: @bastos.sergio how-to-use-a-wsdl-file-to-create-a-wcf-service-not-make-a-call don't anwer my question. i want to know how include summary at my generated code